# Azure Blob Storage Decrypt Using Key Vault .Net v12 SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage

I'm looking to decrypt Azure Storage Blobs encrypted using Azure Key Vault in .NET. Based on this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault?tabs=dotnet11#decrypt-blob-and-download):

But I'm not finding any alternative for decrypting this in v12.

Can you help me with the alternative for these lines of code?

```
  BlobEncryptionPolicy policy = new BlobEncryptionPolicy(null, kvResolver);
       BlobRequestOptions options = new BlobRequestOptions() { EncryptionPolicy = policy, CustomerProvidedKey = new BlobCustomerProvidedKey(aesKey) };

using (var np = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
    blob.DownloadToStream(np, null, options, null);
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello @TheHeadphoneDude, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you –

Answer (score 0):

They are currently working to create code snippets reflecting version 12.x of the Azure Storage client libraries. For more information, see [Announcing the Azure Storage v12 Client Libraries](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-storage/announcing-the-azure-storage-v12-client-libraries/ba-p/1482394).

The v12 storage libraries are also consistent across Azure services, so learning one will make it easier to learn the others. They are supported, fully documented, and open-sourced ([.NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/storage),  [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/storage),  [Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage),  [JS/Node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage)).

Feel free to learn more about the guidelines followed to create these SDKs by visiting the  [.NET guidelines](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/dotnet_introduction.html).

Comment: Is there any workaround for this available currently? If not, can this be done through any other language like python? If yes, can you please share some code snippet for the same? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry  , Currently there is not any workaround in V12 even in  python language it is work in progress.

Comment: Do you have any idea as to when this functionality will be available? The article was released back in 2020 and the link about announcing the new libraries doesn't mention any release date

Comment: @TheHeadphoneDude, Can you run the same code which is showing for v11 in v12 and let me know if you recieve any error?

Comment: I'm trying to run this code in a synapse notebook and it isn't allowing me to install the v11 packages as those are deprecated. What should I do?

Comment: @TheHeadphoneDude, In your synapase notebook which has version 12 installed . Try to run the same code which was used in V11. Please let me know if you are getting any error.